# How to mark an empty array as Null when Parsing data from Json Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing

So I have successfully managed to parse the JSON data shown below:

```
    [
{
"IsRecentlyVerified": false,
"ID": 136888,
"UUID": "254B0B07-E7FC-4B4B-A37C-899BCB9D7261",
"DataProviderID": 18,
"DataProvidersReference": "0a9fdbb17feb6ccb7ec405cfb85222c4",
"OperatorID": 3,
"UsageTypeID": 1,
"AddressInfo": {
"ID": 137234,
"Title": "Ballee Road Park & Share",
"AddressLine1": "Ballee Road",
"Town": "Ballymena",
"Postcode": "BT42 2HD",
"CountryID": 1,
"Latitude": 54.844648,
"Longitude": -6.273606,
"AccessComments": "Ballee Road Park and Share, Ballymena",
"RelatedURL": "http://pod-point.com",
"Distance": 3.812940207797744,
"DistanceUnit": 2
},
"Connections": [
{
"ID": 191571,
"ConnectionTypeID": 25,
"Reference": "1",
"StatusTypeID": 50,
"LevelID": 2,
"Amps": 32,
"Voltage": 400,
"PowerKW": 22,
"CurrentTypeID": 20
},
{
"ID": 191572,
"ConnectionTypeID": 25,
"Reference": "2",
"StatusTypeID": 50,
"LevelID": 2,
"Amps": 32,
"Voltage": 400,
"PowerKW": 22,
"CurrentTypeID": 20
}
],
"StatusTypeID": 0,
"DateLastStatusUpdate": "2020-02-21T15:15:00Z",
"MetadataValues": [
{
"ID": 6740,
"MetadataFieldID": 4,
"ItemValue": "Contains public sector information licensed under the Open Government Licence v2.0. http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/2/"
}
],
"DataQualityLevel": 3,
"DateCreated": "2019-12-24T05:23:00Z",
"SubmissionStatusTypeID": 100
},
{
"IsRecentlyVerified": false,
"ID": 48636,
"UUID": "69C483E6-E271-4315-A56F-E3747EA59D52",
"DataProviderID": 1,
"OperatorID": 93,
"OperatorsReference": "SC99",
"UsageTypeID": 4,
"UsageCost": "Free",
"AddressInfo": {
"ID": 48982,
"Title": "Dunsilly Park and Ride, Dunsilly Roundabout",
"AddressLine1": "Dunsilly Park and Ride, Dunsilly Roundabout,",
"Town": "Antrim",
"Postcode": "BT41 2JH",
"CountryID": 1,
"Latitude": 54.74636,
"Longitude": -6.234244,
"Distance": 4.081140533868653,
"DistanceUnit": 2
},
"Connections": [
{
"ID": 60091,
"ConnectionTypeID": 25,
"Reference": "1",
"StatusTypeID": 50,
"LevelID": 2,
"Amps": 32,
"Voltage": 400,
"PowerKW": 22,
"CurrentTypeID": 20,
"Quantity": 2
}
],
```

With the data struct file:

```
import Foundation

struct PublicCharger: Decodable {
    let AddressInfo: AddressInfo
    let Connections: [Connections]
    
}

struct AddressInfo: Decodable {
    let Title: String
    let Latitude: Double
    let Longitude: Double
}

struct Connections: Decodable {
    let StatusTypeID: Int
    let ConnectionTypeID: Int
    let PowerKW: Int

}
```

In my View Controller:

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode([PublicCharger].self, from: data)
            if !decodedData.isEmpty {
                //print("Ran")
                //print("Data: \(decodedData[0].AddressInfo.Title)")
                let count = 0...10
                for i in count {
                    publicChargerTitle.append(decodedData[i].AddressInfo.Title)
                    publicChargerLatitude.append(decodedData[i].AddressInfo.Latitude)
                    publicChargerLongitude.append(decodedData[i].AddressInfo.Longitude)
                    publicChargerStatus1.append(decodedData[i].Connections[0].StatusTypeID)
                    publicChargerStatus2.append(decodedData[i].Connections[1].StatusTypeID)
                    publicChargerConnector1.append(decodedData[i].Connections[0].ConnectionTypeID)
                    publicChargerConnector2.append(decodedData[i].Connections[1].ConnectionTypeID)
                    publicChargerKW1.append(decodedData[i].Connections[0].PowerKW)
                    publicChargerKW2.append(decodedData[i].Connections[1].PowerKW)
                }
```

This works and adds the data to its own array.

The issue I'm seeing is not all chargers have the same number of connections. So when parsed the arrays are not matching each other at the end. Instead of skipping that array allocation with the next charger data, is there a way I can instead insert Null into the array to hold its place?

I have looked around and haven't yet found a clear solution to this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. API data from: https://api.openchargemap.io/

Thanks

Comment: Don’t do this, use one array with your custom type and not multiple arrays with single values.

Comment: So as per the comment above I created a class called PublicChargers and added all properties. I have then created an array with the type PublicChargers. However my issue still stands, it picks up the parsed data where index 2 of connections doesn't exist and causes it to crash with index out of range. How would I get it to skip the empty response and instead replace it with null.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect to have 2 connections or rather why you you have to hard code the indices when accessing them instead of using a `for` loop for instance? If you really need to use the hard coded variant you can have a function that checks the size of the array and then either return a connection or nil